# How to add to regular expression all strange symbol for validation my product urls?

Tags: php, regular-language

For validation utls I used this regular expression. But time to time I faced with strange symbol and I should add it to my expression, how to add all possible strange symbol to my expression ?

```
const PATTERN = '~^
    (http|https)://                                 # protocol
    (([\_\.\pL\pN-]+:)?([\_\.\pL\pN-]+)@)?  # basic auth
    (
        ([\pL\pN\pS\-\_\.])+(\.?([\pL\pN]|xn\-\-[\pL\pN-]+)+\.?) # a domain name
            |                                                 # or
        \d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}                    # an IP address
            |                                                 # or
        \[
            (?:(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4})):){6})(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4})):(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4})))|(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:25[0-5]|(?:[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-4])?[0-9]))\.){3}(?:(?:25[0-5]|(?:[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-4])?[0-9])))))))|(?:(?:::(?:(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4})):){5})(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4})):(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4})))|(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:25[0-5]|(?:[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-4])?[0-9]))\.){3}(?:(?:25[0-5]|(?:[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-4])?[0-9])))))))|(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4})))?::(?:(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4})):){4})(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4})):(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4})))|(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:25[0-5]|(?:[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-4])?[0-9]))\.){3}(?:(?:25[0-5]|(?:[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-4])?[0-9])))))))|(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4})):){0,1}(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4})))?::(?:(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4})):){3})(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4})):(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4})))|(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:25[0-5]|(?:[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-4])?[0-9]))\.){3}(?:(?:25[0-5]|(?:[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-4])?[0-9])))))))|(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4})):){0,2}(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4})))?::(?:(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4})):){2})(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4})):(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4})))|(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:25[0-5]|(?:[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-4])?[0-9]))\.){3}(?:(?:25[0-5]|(?:[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-4])?[0-9])))))))|(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4})):){0,3}(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4})))?::(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4})):)(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4})):(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4})))|(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:25[0-5]|(?:[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-4])?[0-9]))\.){3}(?:(?:25[0-5]|(?:[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-4])?[0-9])))))))|(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4})):){0,4}(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4})))?::)(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4})):(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4})))|(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:25[0-5]|(?:[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-4])?[0-9]))\.){3}(?:(?:25[0-5]|(?:[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-4])?[0-9])))))))|(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4})):){0,5}(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4})))?::)(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4})))|(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4})):){0,6}(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4})))?::))))
        \]  # an IPv6 address
    )
    (:[0-9]+)?                              # a port (optional)
    (?:/ (?:[\pL\pN\-._\~!$&\'()*+,;=:@]|%[0-9A-Fa-f]{2})* )*          # a path
    (?:\? (?:[\pL\pN\-._\~!$&\'\[\]()*+,;=:@/?]|%[0-9A-Fa-f]{2})* )?   # a query (optional)
    (?:\# (?:[\pL\pN\-._\~!$&\'()*+,;=:@/?]|%[0-9A-Fa-f]{2})* )?       # a fragment (optional)
$~ixu';
```

and my approach for validate url by this pattern

```
if (!preg_match($pattern, $value)) {
    do something, add throwing exception or something like that
}
```

bu I faced every time with new strange symbol in url and that's why got failed case, but this urls works correct, redict correct and I need to ad this all possible strange symbol to my regular expression, now I added two symbol `™` and `®`

```
const PATTERN = '~^
            (%s)://                                 # protocol
            (([\_\.\pL\pN-]+:)?([\_\.\pL\pN-]+)@)?  # basic auth
            (
                ([\pL\pN\pS\-\_\.])+(\.?([\pL\pN]|xn\-\-[\pL\pN-]+)+\.?) # a domain name
                    |                                                 # or
                \d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}                    # an IP address
                    |                                                 # or
                \[
                    (?:(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4})):){6})(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4})):(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4})))|(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:25[0-5]|(?:[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-4])?[0-9]))\.){3}(?:(?:25[0-5]|(?:[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-4])?[0-9])))))))|(?:(?:::(?:(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4})):){5})(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4})):(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4})))|(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:25[0-5]|(?:[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-4])?[0-9]))\.){3}(?:(?:25[0-5]|(?:[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-4])?[0-9])))))))|(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4})))?::(?:(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4})):){4})(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4})):(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4})))|(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:25[0-5]|(?:[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-4])?[0-9]))\.){3}(?:(?:25[0-5]|(?:[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-4])?[0-9])))))))|(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4})):){0,1}(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4})))?::(?:(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4})):){3})(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4})):(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4})))|(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:25[0-5]|(?:[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-4])?[0-9]))\.){3}(?:(?:25[0-5]|(?:[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-4])?[0-9])))))))|(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4})):){0,2}(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4})))?::(?:(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4})):){2})(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4})):(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4})))|(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:25[0-5]|(?:[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-4])?[0-9]))\.){3}(?:(?:25[0-5]|(?:[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-4])?[0-9])))))))|(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4})):){0,3}(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4})))?::(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4})):)(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4})):(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4})))|(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:25[0-5]|(?:[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-4])?[0-9]))\.){3}(?:(?:25[0-5]|(?:[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-4])?[0-9])))))))|(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4})):){0,4}(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4})))?::)(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4})):(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4})))|(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:25[0-5]|(?:[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-4])?[0-9]))\.){3}(?:(?:25[0-5]|(?:[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-4])?[0-9])))))))|(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4})):){0,5}(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4})))?::)(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4})))|(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4})):){0,6}(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4})))?::))))
                \]  # an IPv6 address
            )
            (:[0-9]+)?                              # a port (optional)
            (?:/ (?:[\pL\pN\-._\~!$&\'()*+™®,;=:@]|%%[0-9A-Fa-f]{2})* )*          # a path
            (?:\? (?:[\pL\pN\-._\~!$&\'\[\]()*+™®,;=:@/?]|%%[0-9A-Fa-f]{2})* )?   # a query (optional)
            (?:\# (?:[\pL\pN\-._\~!$&\'()*+™®,;=:@/?]|%%[0-9A-Fa-f]{2})* )?       # a fragment (optional)
        $~ixu';
```

but how to add all possible strange symbols ? Small example set which I faced `¤æø™®`

Comment: have you tested `https://regex101.com`? those patterns seems extremely unnecessary complex. without example urls, its hard to judge whats a good vs bad url.

Comment: Are you trying to validate any specific format defined by yourself here, or are you just trying to check if the given value is a valid URL in general? For the latter, PHP already has `FILTER_VALIDATE_URL` …

Comment: I think not all obviously, because symfony validator use this way with regular expression